# Trouble installing therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, therubyracer

so I am trying to install BeEF (http://beefproject.com/) on xubuntu 13.10 but I keep getting an error with therubyracer while trying to bundle install.

here are the directions I am following. (from BeEF's github page)

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install curl git ruby build-essential libsqlite3-ruby libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
sudo curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
rvm pkg install zlib --verify-downloads 1
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p484
rvm use 1.9.3
gem install bundler
git clone git://github.com/beefproject/beef.git
cd beef
bundle install <---- error here
ruby beef
```

Here is the error code when I run bundle install:

```
Installing therubyracer (0.12.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling heap.cc
compiling date.cc
compiling object.cc
compiling init.cc
compiling constraints.cc
compiling external.cc
compiling constants.cc
compiling signature.cc
compiling locker.cc
compiling rr.cc
compiling handles.cc
compiling value.cc
compiling string.cc
compiling accessor.cc
compiling context.cc
compiling message.cc
compiling gc.cc
compiling array.cc
compiling template.cc
compiling function.cc
compiling backref.cc
compiling trycatch.cc
compiling script.cc
compiling v8.cc
compiling invocation.cc
compiling stack.cc
compiling primitive.cc
compiling exception.cc
linking shared-object v8/init.so
/usr/bin/ld: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-     3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a(api.o): relocation      R_ARM_THM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `_ZN2v88internal7Isolate12isolate_key_E' can not be used when     making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-    3.16.14.3/vendor/v8/out/arm.release/obj.target/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a: error adding symbols:     Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [init.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for     inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am using ruby 1.9.3-p484 as well as ruby gems version 2.2.2. If anyone has a solution that would be awesome!

Comment: try installing node.js for your os instead.

Comment: try installing g++ and gcc